# SharePoint send notification by assignation

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-workflow

I created in SharePoint a list. It has several columns, one of these columns is called assined to. It contains one or more person. 
What i want, is that an email is send to the new person/s, if a new person is added to this column.
Now i searched a little bit, and found out that I should use Workflows to solve this problem. But the problem is the Workflow is started only automaticly if any changes are made in an element or when an element is created.

So my question is, is theire a possibility to trigger an email by content changes in a specified column.

By the way im working  with a list in SharePoint 2013.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to accomplish this is to use an additional column on the list to track the previous assignment. Whenever an item is modified, the workflow can run and check the Assigned To field against the new Previous Assignment field. If they are different, the workflow can send the email and then update the Previous Assignment field to be equal to the current Assigned To value.

You can make the Previous Assignment field hidden from forms in the content type settings so that it won't be visible (and confusing) to users.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this would work. You would need to create a condition which checks on every change which is made to the item if the field "assigned to" is filled.

Here is nearly the same requirement at the MSDN Forums:

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/112c2be9-5d3e-47d1-ad1c-06312de8a925/workflow-condition-assigned-to-is-not-empty?forum=sharepointcustomization